# Why does this code using UndecidableInstances compile, then generate a runtime infinite loop?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, undecidable-instances

When writing some code using `UndecidableInstances` earlier, I ran into something that I found very odd. I managed to unintentionally create some code that typechecks when I believed it should not:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data Foo = Foo

class ConvertFoo a b where
  convertFoo :: a -> b

instance (ConvertFoo a Foo, ConvertFoo Foo b) => ConvertFoo a b where
  convertFoo = convertFoo . (convertFoo :: a -> Foo)

evil :: Int -> String
evil = convertFoo
```

Specifically, the `convertFoo` function typechecks when given *any* input to produce *any* output, as demonstrated by the `evil` function. At first, I thought that perhaps I managed to accidentally implement `unsafeCoerce`, but that is not quite true: actually attempting to call my `convertFoo` function (by doing something like `evil 3`, for example) simply goes into an infinite loop.

I *sort of* understand what’s going on in a vague sense. My understanding of the problem is something like this:

- The instance of `ConvertFoo` that I have defined works on *any* input and output, `a` and `b`, only limited by the two additional constraints that conversion functions must exist from `a -> Foo` and `Foo -> b`.
- Somehow, that definition is able to match any input and output types, so it would seem that the call to `convertFoo :: a -> Foo` is picking the very definition of `convertFoo` itself, since it’s the only one available, anyway.
- Since `convertFoo` calls itself infinitely, the function goes into an infinite loop that never terminates.
- Since `convertFoo` never terminates, the type of that definition is bottom, so *technically* none of the types are ever violated, and the program typechecks.

Now, even if the above understanding is correct, I am still confused about why the whole program typechecks. Specifically, I would expect the `ConvertFoo a Foo` and `ConvertFoo Foo b` constraints to fail, given that no such instances exist.

I *do* understand (at least fuzzily) that constraints don’t matter when picking an instance—the instance is picked based solely on the instance head, then constraints are checked—so I could see that those constraints might resolve just fine because of my `ConvertFoo a b` instance, which is about as permissive as it can possibly be. However, that would then require the same set of constraints to be resolved, which I think would put the typechecker into an infinite loop, causing GHC to either hang on compilation or give me a stack overflow error (the latter of which I’ve seen before).

Clearly, though, the typechecker does *not* loop, because it happily bottoms out and compiles my code happily. Why? How is the instance context satisfied in this particular example? Why doesn’t this give me a type error or produce a typechecking loop?

Comment: I like this question! I propose a slightly simpler question kernel: how come compilation of `class Default a where def :: a; instance Default a => Default a where def = def; main = def` terminates?

Comment: @DanielWagner Is the key to both of these that Haskell can equate infinite types? And perhaps more practically, if that is not the behavior I want, is there anything I can do to avoid it to avoid producing bottom? I’d *like* this to only typecheck if those two instances (`ConvertFoo a Foo` and `ConvertFoo Foo b`) are actually defined.

Comment: No infinite types here. And those two instances _are_ actually defined! The declaration `instance ... => Convert a b` says that there is an instance for _every_ stupid pair of types you care to come up with, including if one of them happens to be a `Foo`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, I do understand that, but won’t that prompt recursive evaluation of those constraints? Even if I had defined an instance on any two types, verifying that instance is valid would require recursively checking each pair of types against those same constraints, right? Or does Haskell not check those constraints recursively?

Comment: That's a great question, and one I whole-heartedly upvoted. =)

Comment: I find it interesting to note that the Scala translation of this, using implicits, is rejected by scalac as a ["diverging implicit expansion"](https://github.com/phipsgabler/scala-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/playground/convertFoo/ConvertFoo.scala).

Comment: @phg that is interesting, provided Scala implicits do in fact handle some of the _correct_ cases of proper `UndecidableInstances`, without the compiler also rejecting them as “diverging”. Does it?

Comment: And FTR: GHC _would_ have put forth more resistance against accepting this instance, if it hadn't been the _only_ one. Any further instance you write in addition to `(ConvertFoo a Foo, ConvertFoo Foo b) => ConvertFoo a b` will be _overlapping_, not just undecidable, and `OverlappingInstances` are well-known to be risky beyond compile-time.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have the feeling that Scala implicits allow for strictly more cases, but I'm not sure. Could you point me to a short "proper usage example" to translate? [Here's](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters) at least the specification of the termination checking.

Comment: @phg: `class Foo x` and `class Bar x` with `instance Bar (x,y) => Foo (x,y)` is undecidable yet safe.

Comment: @leftaroundabout [Seems to work](https://github.com/phipsgabler/scala-playground/blob/531e959dc4dec2ac4caedf1cdbeea5bb3cf55b4a/src/main/scala/playground/convertFoo/ConvertFoo.scala#L56).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wholeheartedly agree that this is a great question. It speaks to how
our intuitions about typeclasses differ from the reality.

### Typeclass surprise

To see what is going on here, going to raise the stakes on the
type signature for `evil`:

```
data X

class Convert a b where
  convert :: a -> b

instance (Convert a X, Convert X b) => Convert a b where
  convert = convert . (convert :: a -> X)

evil :: a -> b
evil = convert
```

Clearly the `Covert a b` instance is being chosen as there is only
one instance of this class. The typechecker is thinking something like
this:

- `Convert a X` is true if...

  - `Convert a X` is true [true by assumption]
  - and `Convert X X` is true

    - `Convert X X` is true if...

      - `Convert X X` is true [true by assumption]
      - `Convert X X` is true [true by assumption]
- `Convert X b` is true if...

  - `Convert X X` is true [true from above]
  - and `Convert X b` is true [true by assumption]

The typechecker has surprised us. We do not expect `Convert X X` to be
true as we have not defined anything like it. But `(Convert X X, Convert X X) => Convert X X` is a kind of tautology: it is
automatically true and it is true no matter what methods are defined in the class.

This might not match our mental model of typeclasses. We expect the
compiler to gawk at this point and complain about how `Convert X X`
cannot be true because we have defined no instance for it. We expect
the compiler to stand at the `Convert X X`, to look for another spot
to walk to where `Convert X X` is true, and to give up because there
is no other spot where that is true. But the compiler is able to
recurse! Recurse, loop, and be Turing-complete.

We blessed the typechecker with this capability, and we did it with
`UndecidableInstances`. When the documentation states that it is
possible to send the compiler into a loop it is easy to assume the
worst and we assumed that the bad loops are always infinite loops. But
here we have demonstrated a loop even deadlier, a loop that
*terminates* – except in a surprising way.

(This is demonstrated even more starkly in Daniel's comment:

```
class Loop a where
  loop :: a

instance Loop a => Loop a where
  loop = loop
```

.)

### The perils of undecidability

This is the exact sort of situation that `UndecidableInstances`
allows. If we turn that extension off and turn `FlexibleContexts` on
(a harmless extension that is just syntactic in nature), we get a
warning about a violation of one of the [Paterson
conditions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-termination-rules):

```
...
Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
  in the constraint: Convert a X
(Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the instance declaration for ‘Convert a b’

...
Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
  in the constraint: Convert X b
(Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the instance declaration for ‘Convert a b’
```

"No smaller than instance head," although we can mentally rewrite it
as "it is possible this instance will be used to prove an assertion of
itself and cause you much anguish and gnashing and typing." The
Paterson conditions together prevent looping in instance resolution.
Our violation here demonstrates why they are necessary, and we can
presumably consult some paper to see why they are sufficient.

### Bottoming out

As for why the program at runtime infinite loops: There is the boring
answer, where `evil :: a -> b` cannot but infinite loop or throw an
exception or generally bottom out because we trust the Haskell
typechecker and there is no value that can inhabit `a -> b` except
bottom.

A more interesting answer is that, since `Convert X X` is
tautologically true, its instance definition is this infinite loop

```
convertXX :: X -> X
convertXX = convertXX . convertXX
```

We can similarly expand out the `Convert A B` instance definition.

```
convertAB :: A -> B
convertAB =
  convertXB . convertAX
  where
    convertAX = convertXX . convertAX
    convertXX = convertXX . convertXX
    convertXB = convertXB . convertXX
```

This surprising behavior, and how constrained instance resolution (by
default without extensions) is meant to be as to avoid these
behaviors, perhaps can be taken as a good reason for why Haskell's
typeclass system has yet to pick up wide adoption. Despite its
impressive popularity and power, there are odd corners to it (whether
it is in documentation or error messages or syntax or maybe even in
its underlying logic) that seem particularly ill fit to how we humans
think about type-level abstractions.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your very detailed answer! Unfortunately, I seem to remain a tiny bit unsatisfied. I think I understood *most* of these things, especially the key fact that `Convert X X` already exists, given that we have defined `Convert a b`, but the description of the typechecker’s “thought process” confuses me. If it determines that “`Convert X X` is true if `Convert X X` is true”, it has not proven anything—that is just a tautology! If that sufficed as a proof, we could prove that *any* instance exists. Why does the recursion make things special?

Comment: Take a constraint that we know not to be true. For example, `Num String`. We _could_ define `instance Num String`. We could _also_ define an `instance Num a => Num a`. Now `Num String` also holds! This is oh-so-slightly different from a true tautology, which I agree would be useless, because `instance Num a => Num a` is equivalent to `instance Num a`, which actually _does_ do something. // Of course we would have to implement some of the `Num` methods in `instance Num a` with bottom ... exactly what we did here!

Comment: Ahh, I think I see now, yes. One more nuance to add on top of my ever-growing mental picture of Haskell typeclasses. I suppose it’s worth asking one more thing, though if it needs to be a whole separate question, perhaps it should be: is there any way to encode the thing I actually *want* into Haskell’s type system? That is, I want an instance of `ConvertFoo` from `a` to `b` if, and *only* if, `ConvertFoo a Foo` and `ConvertFoo Foo b` instances exist? Or is that really not currently possible with how typeclass resolution works?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I mentally process these cases:

```
class ConvertFoo a b where convertFoo :: a -> b
instance (ConvertFoo a Foo, ConvertFoo Foo b) => ConvertFoo a b where
  convertFoo = ...

evil :: Int -> String
evil = convertFoo
```

First, we start by computing the set of required instances.

- `evil` directly requires `ConvertFoo Int String` (1).
- Then, (1) requires `ConvertFoo Int Foo` (2) and `ConvertFoo Foo String` (3).
- Then, (2) requires `ConvertFoo Int Foo` (we already counted this) and `ConvertFoo Foo Foo` (4).
- Then (3) requires `ConvertFoo Foo Foo` (counted) and `ConvertFoo Foo String` (counted).
- Then (4) requires `ConvertFoo Foo Foo` (counted) and `ConvertFoo Foo Foo` (counted).

Hence, we reach a fixed point, which is a finite set of required instances. The compiler has no trouble with computing that set in finite time: just apply the instance definitions until no more constraint is needed.

Then, we proceed to provide the code for those instances. Here it is.

```
convertFoo_1 :: Int -> String
convertFoo_1 = convertFoo_3 . convertFoo_2
convertFoo_2 :: Int -> Foo
convertFoo_2 = convertFoo_4 . convertFoo_2
convertFoo_3 :: Foo -> String
convertFoo_3 = convertFoo_3 . convertFoo_4
convertFoo_4 :: Foo -> Foo
convertFoo_4 = convertFoo_4 . convertFoo_4
```

We get a bunch of mutually recursive instance definitions. These, in this case, will loop at runtime, but there's no reason to reject them at compile time.